# Sorting Elements in Groups - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix-indexing

I have an array A having `x` and `y` values.. e,g.

```
A = 
    5  1
    7  2
    3  1
    5  3
    4  4
    7  3
    2  5
    9  5
    7  6
```

I need to take three values at one time and sort them in ascending order according to the `x` values (First 3 `x y` values Then next 3 `x y` values and so on. )

I want it in this order -

```
3  1
5  1
7  2
4  4
5  3
7  3
2  5
7  6
9  5
```

Can somebody suggest me a MATLAB code to get the required result?

Thank You

Comment: @Shahbaz you must try solve it yourself first and tell us where you got stuck or at least what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Dan I am dealing with pixel coordinates and so far arranged the values in ascending order according to y values. I am stucked in the algorithm how can i select just 3 at one time sort them and move on.

Comment: @Shahbaz have you tried using a loop? Also you can select three items like this: `A(4:6)` or if you're looping on a variable like `for x = 1:3:size(A,1)` then `A(x:(x+2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
N = 3; %// group-size
[~,ind] = sort(reshape(A(:,1),N,[])) %// get sorted indices for the x values as 
                                     %// groups of N elements
Aout = A(bsxfun(@plus,ind,[0:(size(A,1)/N)-1]*N),:) %// get sorted indices for all
%// x values as a whole and use them to index into rows of A to get the desired output
```

Of course it assumes that the number of rows is divisible by `N`.